# How do you view DHCP servers within VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dhcp, dhcp-server

I set up a DHCP server within VirtualBox long ago and I wish to remove it. The VBoxManage dhcpserver does not have an option to list the servers -- only remove, add, or modify. I can't "tab" through the servers.

Further clarification, you are able to DHCP create servers within VirtualBox by going to `Oracle/VirtualBox/` and then using the command:

```
VBoxManage.exe dhcpserver add { --network=netname | --interface=ifname } {--server-ip=address} {--netmask=mask} {--lower-ip=address} {--upper-ip=address} { --enable | --disable }
```

There is no command to list the dhcpservers within VirtualBox and it is now set as my default dhcpserver. So every VM I make, VirtualBox uses the dhcpserver I set up for testing purposes. I want to remove it and go back to the original dhcpserver, but I need the name of the name, but have no way to view it (that I know of). There is no documentation on this. I know I could remove, modify the dhcpservers, but I need to know the names. So, is there a way to view the names.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please clarify how you "set up a DHCP server". As a VM, or did you use the inbuilt DHCP capability of VirtualBox? If the latter, of course you cannot remove it ... If it's a VM, why can't you remove the VM?

Comment: @Community Clarified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are able to view the DHCPServers within VirtualBox by going to `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox` and using the following command:

```
VBoxManage.exe list dhcpservers
```

This will list all the DHCPServers used by VirtualBox. To remove the DHCP Server, you do the following:

```
VBoxManage.exe dhcpserver remove { --network=netname | --interface=ifname }
```

Comment: `VBoxManage.exe list dhcpservers` does not list the "virtual NAT engine" DHCP servers which VirtualBox sets up "behind the scene" for each network interface of type "NAT" separately, for each virtual machine separately - right? (e.g. the default NAT router/DHCP server with IP address `10.0.2.2`). https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat ... how to find out and modify those DHCP servers' configuration, e.g. their MAC address?